# searching through a short sorted array of doubles

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I am trying to optimize a search through a very short sorted array of doubles to locate a bucket a given `value` belongs to. Assuming the size of the array is 8 doubles, I have come up with the following sequence of AVX intrinsics:

```
_data = _mm256_load_pd(array);
temp  = _mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_cmp_pd(_data, _value, _CMP_LT_OQ));
pos   = _mm_popcnt_u32(temp);
_data = _mm256_load_pd(array+4);
temp  = _mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_cmp_pd(_data, _value, _CMP_LT_OQ));
pos  += _mm_popcnt_u32(temp);
```

To my surprise (I do not have the instruction latency specs in my head..), it turned out that a faster code is generated by gcc for the following C loop:

```
for(i=0; i<7; ++i) if(array[i+1]>=value) break;
```

This loop compiles into what I found to be a very efficient code:

```
lea ecx, [rax+1]
vmovsd  xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8]
vucomisd    xmm1, xmm0
jae .L7

lea ecx, [rax+2]
vmovsd  xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8]
vucomisd    xmm1, xmm0
jae .L8

[... repeat for all elements of array]
```

so it takes 4 instructions to check 1 bucket (`lea`, `vmovsd`, `vucomisd`, `jae`). Assuming the `value` is uniformly spread, on average I will have to check ~3.5 buckets per `value`. Apparently, this is enough to outperform the AVX code listed earlier.

Now, in a general case the array may of course be larger than 8 elements. If I code a C loop like this:

```
for(i=0; u<n-1; i++) if(array[i+1]>=value) break;
```

I get the following instruction sequence for the loop body:

```
.L76:
mov eax, edx
.L67:
cmp eax, esi
jae .L77
lea edx, [rax+1]
mov ecx, edx
vmovsd  xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdi+rcx*8]
vucomisd    xmm1, xmm0
jb  .L76
```

I can tell gcc to unroll the loop, but the point is that the number of instructions per element is larger than in the case of the loop with constant bounds, and the code is slower. Also, I do not understand the reason behind using an additional `rcx` register for addressing in `vmovsd`.

I can manually modify the assembly for the loop to look something like in the first example, and it does work faster:

```
.L76:
cmp edx, esi            # eax -> edx
jae .L77
lea edx, [rdx+1]        # rax -> rdx
vmovsd  xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdi+rdx*8]
vucomisd    xmm1, xmm0
jb  .L76
```

but I can not seem to make gcc do it. And I know it can - the asm generated in the first example is OK.

Do you have any ideas how to do it otherwise than using inline asm? Or even better - can you suggest a faster implementation of the search?

Comment: +1 but "_I can tell gcc to unroll the loop...in this case, and the code is slower_", for **your specific processor**. I think you're going little bit **too forward in your optimization** and risk is to **best match only architecture of your test machine** (with, maybe, poor performance in anything else). Of course if you're not optimizing something for an embedded system where CPU is fixed and won't change over time.

Comment: @Adriano I was not precise - the unrolled code for the loop with general bounds is slower than the code generated for the loop with constant bounds. I do not expect this to be very much platform dependent - there simply are 2 instructions less. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Here I just guess because I don't see what gcc generated but I would check for cache size (1st level cache), branch prediction or pipeline stuffs

Comment: @angainor "Now, in a general case the array may of course be larger than 8 elements" as you've mentioned that it's a sorted array, an O(log(n)) search may (slightly) increase the performance.

Comment: @starrify Thanks, of course I already do that for large arrays. I have a octal-tree structure - that's why I need a search in an array of 8 elements. Plus, I need a general short search in the tree leaves.

Comment: Can you share how you initialized _value? Also did you try using a different pointer for the second half - this can for the compiler to use more registers.

Comment: @egur  `value` is a function parameter of type `double`. `_value` in the AVX implementation is initialized by simply by `_value = _mm256_set1_pd(value);`. What do you mean by different pointer? I have an array of doubles, that is a `double *`.

Comment: I meant using data1 for start of array and using another (data2) for the second half: _data2 = _mm256_load_pd(array+4);

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but there's no room in the comments for this.

I tested the AVX function against a simple C implementation and got completely different results.
I tested on Windows 7 x64 not Linux but the generated code was very similar.
How the test went:
1) I disabled the CPU's SpeedStep.
2) Within main() I raised the process priority and thread priority to the max (realtime).
3) I ran 10M calls to the tested function to heat up the CPU - activate turbo.
4) I called Sleep(0) to avoid a context switch
5) I called __rdtscp to start measurement
6) in a loop I called either the AVX find index function or the simple C version - like you did. the other implementation was commented out and not used. Loop size was 10M calls.
7) I called __rdtscp  again to finish the benchmark.
8) I printed ticks/iterations. to get the average tick count for a call

Note: I declared both 'find index' functions as inline and I confirmed in the disassembly that they got inlined.
The AVX function and the C functions you described are not identical, the C function return a zero based index and the AVX functio returns a 1 based index.
On my system, it took the AVX function 1.1 cycles per iteration and the C function took 4.4 cycles per iteration.

I couldn't force the MSVC compiler to use more than ymm registers :(

Array used:

```
double A[8] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 };
```

Results (avg. ticks/iter):
value = 0.3 (index = 2): AVX: 1.1 | C: 4.4
value = 0.5 (index = 3): AVX: 1.1 | C: 11.1
value = 0.9 (index = 7): AVX: 1.1 | C: 18.1

If the AVX function is corrected to return pos-1, then it will be 50% slower.
You can see that the AVX function works in constant time while the trivial C loop function performance depends on the index you're looking for.

Timing with clock() and running 100M yields similar results, AVX is almost x4 faster for the first test.
Also note that running longer tests reveal different results, but every time AVX holds a similar advantage.

Comment: Thank you for this effort! So the asm code generated for the static C function was like I have posted. Did you test on randomly generated data? Also, it seems not possible that the AVX code only takes 1 cycle. Can you look at time measurements instead of rdtscp? I will try to run the tests using the steps you have mentioned. I have previously timed the code in a different context - in a tree traversal implementation. It is possible that the results will be different, although I am not sure why that would be. One thing - why would `pos-1` decrease the performance so much??

Comment: I used the same data (array), as long as the array is sorted, the instruction behave the same. The CPU pipelines the calculations and have multiple resources for doing SSE/AVX computation, so an average of ~1 instruction is great and feasible. Branch prediction hit rate should be 99.999999% since the loop is simple and long. Decoding is also quick since it's the same 6-8 instructions again and again. In any case the results were very consistent across multiple runs. In the C function, branch prediction isn't as good because the loop is short. I can try measuring with wall time.

Comment: I have tried and in the case of a single static `array` the code is further (unrealistically) optimized to move the loads of `array` elements outside of the loop. That is a bit too much ;) In this case, testing for array of 10e7 SORTED input `value`s, AVX location takes 4.2 cycle per value, unrolled "loop" takes 5.2 cycles per value. AVX is a bit faster(!). 1 clock cycle is not realistic (at least on my machine) since you would then go beyond the memory bandwidth when reading `value`s. Unless you do not read those, but then everything is in registers for the whole duration of the loop...

Comment: There's zero memory bandwidth here, everything quickly end up in the L1 cache - both code and data. As for the code, since it's so small, it's uOPs are cached in the processors DSB unit... All in all, this sort of optimization will probably not matter much in your overall application

Comment: `value` is stored in an array with 10e7 values in total. Of course I am not interested in repeatedly searching for the same value in a static set of bins. In real code, both the value searched, and the bins change. But thanks for the effort, I will do some more work to see if anything can be done..

Comment: Working on a (16B aligned) copy of the array gives the same results. I'll test random too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try integer comparison. Double comparison is equivalent to int64_t comparison of the same bits with exception for NaNs. It could turn faster. CPU has more integer execution units then SIMD. Just send double* and receive int64_t* in function argument.